# Unable to run 2nd test function in python selenium unittest

Tags: python, selenium

In the below code i am unable to run second test function **def testclick(self)**

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class LoginMaharaOrgLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(inst):
        inst.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        #inst.driver.maximize_window()
        inst.driver.get("https://demo.mahara.org/")


    def testlogin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.assertEqual("Home - Mahara Demo", driver.title)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_login_username']").send_keys("student")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_login_password']").send_keys("MaharaDemo")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_submit']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='icon icon-chevron-down collapsed']").click()
        sleep(3)


    def testclick(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Logout']").click()



    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(inst):
        inst.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When i run the above code i am getting the error as:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

Hi
======================================================================
ERROR: testclick (Login.LoginMaharaOrgLogin)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Keerthiaradhya\eclipse-workspace\Unit_Test\Login.py", line 25, in testclick
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Logout']").click()
  File "C:\Users\Keerthiaradhya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Keerthiaradhya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Keerthiaradhya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Keerthiaradhya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='Logout']"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 18.020s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

But if i include this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Logout']").click()
```

statement in `def testlogin(self)` it works

Comment: You are assigning that self.driver to driver variable. Try to use the same in the next function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
def testclick(self):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Logout']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

unittest framework executes test functions based on the name of the function and not in the order that is placed. in your case its executing testclick() first & it's not finding the element. so use `test1_login(self):` and `test2_logout(self):` as function name it will work.